# log4j not logging the details coming from some java classes

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am trying to log data from my project into files based on the input parameter. My project has 5 classes of which 3 contain log messages.

I used the following code to configure log4j.

```
public static void configureLog4j(String log4j,String logs,String timeStamp) throws IOException {
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4j);      
    FileAppender fileapp = (FileAppender) Logger.getRootLogger().getAppender("FILE");
    if(fileapp != null)
        logger.removeAppender(fileapp);
    String filename = logs + "/test_" + info + "_" + timeStamp;
    fileapp.setFile(filename);
    fileapp.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"));
    fileapp.setWriter(new FileWriter(new File(fileapp.getFile())));
    Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(fileapp);
}
```

info represent name of the user. Now once I configure this in the beginning of the applications only two classes are writing logs in the file the third file which contains code to send & receive data does not write the logs to the log file. Is there any thing I am missing here.

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: If this code works for 2 classes over three then the error may come from the third class. Give us the code of the third one, how you call your logger. Also check with debug or println that you reach the line that log data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are that the third class is already logging before you have a chance to configure your logger. This is one reason why I switched to logback: It has a much more powerful (and better documented) config file format.

The code above also contains a problem:

```
if(fileapp != null)
    logger.removeAppender(fileapp);
```

`logger` isn't defined anywhere and `fileapp` must be non-null or you'd get NPEs later.

Comment: logger is a static variable which is created before in the class. I am using the same logger to remove the appender. I used a similar approach in another project and there all the logs were working fine.

Comment: But now you have two appenders configured for the root logger. `logger.removeAppender()` won't do anything unless you have configured another appender for it.

Comment: How did you make sure that no one else uses a logger before the code above is executed?

Answer (score 0):

Please be insure that ***your  third class should not logging*** before configuration.